# OpenCV - Copy GpuMat into cuda device data

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to copy the data in a `cv::cuda::GpuMat` to a `uint8_t*` variable which is to be used in a kernel.

The GpuMat contains an image data of resolution 752x480 and of type CV_8UC1. Below is the sample code:

```
uint8_t *imgPtr;
cv::Mat left, downloadedLeft;
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuLeft;

left = imread("leftview.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
gpuLeft.upload(left);

cudaMalloc((void **)&imgPtr, sizeof(uint8_t)*gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.cols);
cudaMemcpyAsync(imgPtr, gpuLeft.ptr<uint8_t>(), sizeof(uint8_t)*gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

// following code is just for testing and visualization...
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuImg(left.rows, left.cols, left.type(), imgPtr);
gpuImg.download(downloadedLeft);
imshow ("test", downloadedLeft);
waitKey(0);
```

But the output is not as expected. Following are the input and output image respectively.

**INPUT**
[image: Input Image]

**OUTPUT**
[image]

I have tried giving the `cv::Mat` source to the `cudaMemcpy`. It seems to be working fine. The issue seems to be with the `cv::cuda::GpuMat` and `cudaMemcpy`. A similar issue is discussed in the [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/167465/how-to-pass-an-already-stored-data-in-gpu-by-gpumat-to-a-kernel/)

Also, if the image with is 256 or 512, the program seems to be working fine.

What is that I am missing? What should be done for the 752x480 image to work properly?

Comment: In the documentation it tells you `In contrast with Mat, in most cases GpuMat::isContinuous() == false . This means that rows are aligned to a size depending on the hardware. Single-row GpuMat is always a continuous matrix.`, I haven't  work that much with the GpuMat so I am not sure how to know how much is being padded and how to avoid it...

Comment: Appreciate your immediate reply @api55. I am also stuck in the same part. Also, I am trying to understand how it works with the image of the width 256 or 512.

Comment: @talonmies can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: No.Literally go and read the GpuMat documentation and look at the step attribute

Comment: @sam , it works because it does not need the padding with such values, probably is a padded to a power of 2 and in this case is not needed. The padding is used to align the rows to a certain number.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the issue is due to the stride(step). The program works fine with width = power of 2. So the solution would be resizing the image in such a way that the image width is in the power of 2. Let me know if that's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenCV GpuMat](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#details) uses strided storage (so the image is not stored contiguously in memory). In short, your example fails for most cases because

1. You don't copy the whole image to the CUDA memory allocation, and
2. You don't correctly specify the memory layout when you create the second GpuMat instance from the GPU pointer.

By my reading of the documentation, you probably want something like this:

```
uint8_t *imgPtr;
cv::Mat left, downloadedLeft;
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuLeft;

left = imread("leftview.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
gpuLeft.upload(left);

cudaMalloc((void **)&imgPtr, gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.step);
cudaMemcpyAsync(imgPtr, gpuLeft.ptr<uint8_t>(), gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.step, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

// following code is just for testing and visualization...
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuImg(left.rows, left.cols, left.type(), imgPtr, gpuLeft.step);
gpuImg.download(downloadedLeft);
imshow ("test", downloadedLeft);
waitKey(0);
```

[Written by someone who has never used OpenCV, not compiled or tested, use at own risk]

The only time your code would work correctly would be when the row pitch of the GpuMat was serendipitously the same as the number of columns times the size of the type stored in the matrix. This is likely to be images with sizes which are round powers of two.