# VideoReader in OpenCV is deprecated. Is there any update from OpenCV or any substitution?

Tags: c++, opencv, nvidia, video-processing

I am doing video decoding to grab frame for some post video processing. I am using opencv Cuda so I really need video reader from opencv cuda. However, I realized:

In NVIDIA Video Codec SDK 8.2.15, it says that

> Support for CUvideosource and the associated APIs including cuvidCreateVideoSource,cuvidCreateVideoSourceW, cuvidDestroyVideoSource, cuvidSetVideoSourceState, cuvidGetVideoSourceState, cuvidGetSourceVideoFormat, cuvidGetSourceAudioFormat will be removed from the decoder API in future SDK versions. Please note that the new decode sample applications in the SDK do not use these APIs, but use FFmpeg instead.

But to use "createVideoReader" in OpenCV Cuda, we need to link "dynlink_nvcuvid.h" that contains

```
tcuvidCreateVideoSource               *cuvidCreateVideoSource;
tcuvidCreateVideoSourceW              *cuvidCreateVideoSourceW;
tcuvidDestroyVideoSource              *cuvidDestroyVideoSource;
tcuvidSetVideoSourceState             *cuvidSetVideoSourceState;
tcuvidGetVideoSourceState             *cuvidGetVideoSourceState;
tcuvidGetSourceVideoFormat            *cuvidGetSourceVideoFormat;
tcuvidGetSourceAudioFormat            *cuvidGetSourceAudioFormat;
```

Is there any update from opencv for video decoding? How do we use FFmpeg in OpenCV to replace "dynlink_nvcuvid.h"? I am trying to use NVIDIA video decoding but I am stuck at converting the video frame to GpuMat.

I am using
Ubuntu 18
Cuda 9.2
OpenCV 3.4.2

For Cuda part, to decode I have used the following code:

```
FFmpegDemuxer demuxer(szInFilePath);
NvDecoder dec(cuContext, demuxer.GetWidth(), demuxer.GetHeight(), true, FFmpeg2NvCodecId(demuxer.GetVideoCodec()));
FramePresenterGL presenter(cuContext, demuxer.GetWidth(), demuxer.GetHeight());
uint8_t *dpFrame = 0;
int nPitch = 0;
int nVideoBytes = 0, nFrameReturned = 0, nFrame = 0;
uint8_t *pVideo = NULL;
uint8_t **ppFrame;
do {
    demuxer.Demux(&pVideo, &nVideoBytes);
    dec.Decode(pVideo, nVideoBytes, &ppFrame, &nFrameReturned);
    if (!nFrame && nFrameReturned)
        LOG(INFO) << dec.GetVideoInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < nFrameReturned; i++) {
        presenter.GetDeviceFrameBuffer(&dpFrame, &nPitch);
        if (dec.GetBitDepth() == 8)
            Nv12ToBgra32((uint8_t *)ppFrame[i], dec.GetWidth(), (uint8_t *)dpFrame, nPitch, dec.GetWidth(), dec.GetHeight());
        else
            P016ToBgra32((uint8_t *)ppFrame[i], 2 * dec.GetWidth(), (uint8_t *)dpFrame, nPitch, dec.GetWidth(), dec.GetHeight());

        cv::Size sz(dec.GetWidth(),dec.GetHeight());
        cv::Mat mat1(sz,CV_8UC3, ppFrame);
        cv::imshow ("test", mat1);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }
    nFrame += nFrameReturned;
} while (nVideoBytes);
```

Anyone has experience on using opencv cuda with actual video codec api? How do I put the video frame into GpuMat?

Update:

I have tried to convert uint8_t but the image is displayed wrongly as shown below: 
[image]

The code i used is updated above. What should I change to display the image correctly? I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520728/7939409 but the downloadedLeft is empty for the code below.

```
cv::Mat downloadedLeft;
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpuLeft;

cudaMalloc((void **)&ppFrame, gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.step);
cudaMemcpyAsync(ppFrame, gpuLeft.ptr<uint8_t>(), gpuLeft.rows*gpuLeft.step, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

gpuLeft.download(downloadedLeft);
cv::imshow ("test", downloadedLeft);
cv::waitKey(1);
```

Comment: Maybe you can write your own library like this guy did https://github.com/vdkkia/Using-Opencv-with-ffmpeg-in-python3-

Comment: @talonmies can you please stop removing cuda tag from my post. I have used cuda's ffmpegdemuxer, NvDecoder and everything related to cuda.

Comment: I removed it once and as it was originally written,. the post had nothing to do with CUDA procgramming. OpenCV isn't CUDA. The NVIDIA video decode SDK isn't CUDA. FFMPEG isn't CUDA

Comment: In original post, I wrote " I am trying to use CUDA video decoding now but I am stuck at converting CUresult to GpuMat. ". CUresult is from CUDA. Do you know about OpenCV? I know you are very experience in CUDA from your profile. Do you know how to convert CUresult to Matrix?

Comment: CUresult is a status code. You cannot convert it to a matrix. It makes no sense to even suggest it

Comment: Then the frame is stored in uint8_t? I am just a cuda beginner.

Comment: @talonmies be nice mate, she is just a new stackoverflow contributor.

Comment: @Vivian: I don't understand what you are asking about. Where in the code you showed? Without meaning to repeat myself, nothing you are asking about is part of CUDA. The NVIDIA Video codec has nothing to do with CUDA per se. It is a standalone API that uses dedicated hardware within the GPU which CUDA has no access to. The only interaction is that you need to use the CUDA driver to make a context and allocate memory for decoding/encoding buffers. If you don't have questions about that, you don't have questions about CUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple c way to read an image without any 3rd party.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int read_image(FILE *rfile, void *buf, int width, int height, int stride, int elem_size)
{
    char *byte_ptr = buf;
    int i;
    int ret = 1;

    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0 || elem_size <= 0)
    {
        goto fail_or_end;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        if (fread(byte_ptr, elem_size, width, rfile) != (size_t)width)
        {
            goto fail_or_end;
        }

        byte_ptr += stride;
    }

    ret = 0;

fail_or_end:
    return ret;
}
```

credit to netflix vmaf open source (file_io.c). Thank you netflix.
After I read the image, I managed to continue process it with cuda.